# How to use await in RxJS

Tags: angular, async-await, rxjs, observable

I am very new in RxJS

Here is my function

```
getData(id): Observable<any> {

    let accessToken = this.getAccessHeader();

    if (!accessToken) {
        // Here I want to wait till following observable completes, and returns value. Till then do not call next line methods i.e. code outside the if block

        this.getTemptoken().subscribe((res) => {
            accessToken = res.result.accessToken,
        });
    }
    const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'accessToken': accessToken
        })
    };
    return this.http.post(
        url,
        {
            'id': id
        }, httpOptions
    ).pipe(map((res) => {
        return res;
    }));
}
```

`getTemptoken` is also an observable, similar function, which calls API and returns token. I want to wait till `getTemptoken` returns value and after that only execute next lines, i.e. code below if block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would rewrite your method to work as you want it.

```
getData(id): Observable<any> {
  let accessToken$ = of(this.getAccessHeader())
    .pipe(
      switchMap(accessToken => accessToken ? of(accessToken) : this.getTemptoken()
        .pipe(
          map(res => res.result.accessToken)
        )
      )
    )

  return accessToken$
    .pipe(
      map(accessToken => {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'accessToken': accessToken
        })
      }),
      switchMap(httpOptions => this.http.post(url, { id }, httpOptions)),
    )
}
```

accessToken$ is responsible for getting accesToken in case this.getAccessHeader() doesn't give us what we want. This is happening inside switchMap, if we have accessToken we return of(accessToken), else we are returning this.getTemptoken().

Then we take accessToken$, turn it into httpOptions and via switchMap we return our desired this.http.post. Finally whoever subscribes to this method will get desired http response.

Answer (score 2):

To use the result of the first observable in the subsequent observable you can use `switchMap` in a pipe, e.g.:

```
of("Hello").pipe(
            switchMap(result => of(result + ", World")),
            switchMap(result => of(result + "!")),
          )
          .subscribe(console.log);
// output: Hello, World!
```

[learnrxjs switchmap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html)

---

If you don't need the result of the previous observable and just want to trigger observables in a specific order, you can use `concat` which waits for every observable to complete before triggering the next observable:

```
concat(
  of(1).pipe(delay(2000)),
  of(2).pipe(delay(500)),
  of(3).pipe(delay(1000))
)
.subscribe(console.log);

// output: 1 2 3
```

[learnrxjs concat](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/concat.html)

---

Additional you can use `toPromise()`, but it's an AntiPattern. Have a look at

[RxJS Observable interop with Promises and Async-Await](https://medium.com/@benlesh/rxjs-observable-interop-with-promises-and-async-await-bebb05306875)

E.g.:

```
const source$ = Observable.interval(1000).take(3); // 0, 1, 2
// waits 3 seconds, then logs "2".
// because the observable takes 3 seconds to complete, and 
// the interval emits incremented numbers starting at 0
async function test() {
  console.log(await source$.toPromise());
}
```

[learnrxjs topromise](http://%20https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/topromise.html)

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, But my requirement is In one observable method, if a specific data is not present then call other observable till then stop the execution of first observable